# send mail from another app with vmware boxer app

Tags: ios, airwatch

we have iphones managed by VMWare airwatch and we use vmware boxer app for emails, contacts etc.

Now, we are developing another app which should be distributed by our own app cataloge and we want to send mails from that new app by using the already configured boxer mail client. 
My question is, is that possible? I know that i have to check email availability in my app with canSendMail() but does ios recognize that the mail client is not the native Mail app rather the VmWare Boxer app.
if i click on a email link in the browser in my iphone, it starts the native mail client where i have to setup a mail account and that's what i exactly not want^^

Thank you very much for your help :)

regards
Chris

Comment: No, you can't use the standard mail frameworks.  You will need to see if the Airwatch client has an API

Comment: Thanks Paulw11 for the info. Does anyone know a discription for that API? I can't find one on the website :( thx

Answer (score 1):

I've found the URL Scheme in the Admin Guide: I hope it's helpful for anyone else too:
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-AirWatch/9.3/VMware%20Boxer%20Admin%20Guide.pdf

Comment: which is ? Can you give the direct answer